# Automorphism from $G$ to $G/N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $T$ an automorphism of $G$. If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $T(N)\subset N$, show how you could use $T$ to define an automorphism of $G/N$.

**My solution:** I have spent some time and eventually I realized that mapping $\phi: G/N\to G/N$ defined by $\phi(Ng)=NT(g)$ is needed mapping.

I have shown that this mapping is well-defined, homomorphism and surjective. But I am not able to show that it is injective. In order to prove injectivity I need show that equality $T(N)=N$ holds.

Can anyone explain how to do it? I cannot  show that $N\subset T(N)$.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $T(N)=N$. Let $G = ({\mathbb Q},+)$ and define $T$ by $T(x)=2x$. Then for $N = {\mathbb Z}$, we have $T(N) \subset N$ but $T(N) \ne N$. Of course you are OK if $N$ is finite.

Comment: @DerekHolt, Indeed you are right. But how to prove that defined map $\phi :G/N\to G/N$ is one-to-one?

Comment: It isn't one-to-one in this example because $1/2+{\mathbb Z}$ is in the kernel.

Comment: @DerekHolt, could you help me to construct automorphism?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: @DerekHolt, so problem from Herstein's book is false :)

Answer (score 2):

Not every automorphism of $G$ induces an automorphism of the quotient group $G/N$: This only happens if the subgroup $N$ is *characteristic*.

For example, consider the automorphisms on the klein 4-groups - none induce automorphisms of the cyclic group of order two, no matter which subgroup you take as your kernel.

On the other hand:

**Lemma.** Let $T$ be an automorphism of the group $G$ and let $N$ be a characteristic subgroup of $G$. Then $T$ induces, in a natural way, an automorphism $\widehat{T}$ of the group $G/N$.

I will leave you to (1) work out what I mean by "natural way" (you are essentially there in your question!) and (2) assuming $G$ is non-abelian, find a non-trivial automorphism $T$ which fixes a given (in fact, arbitrary) normal subgroup.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by the word "natural way" ?

Comment: @RFZ think about it for a while. It is essentially the thing you are missing in your question. (That is, $T(Ng)=NT(g)$ only if...)